# how to merge two totally identicall tables?

Tags: mysql, merge

I want to merge two tables (like `copy-paste` all rows from `t2` to `t1` - except `id`).

New `id` should be created in `t1` for each inserted rows, as normally.

The two tables are totally identicall - each row, each column are the same.

In fact `t2` is created by duplicating `t1`;

I tried this:

```
insert into t1 (date, img, roll... all t1 columns except id)
select date, img, roll... all t2 columns except id ... from t2;
```

Result - `t1.rows` are just **replaced** by `t2.rows` !!

How to do this?

Comment: [Nothing wrong](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9GtMBEKS3A3G4c4hAJmPp/0) with it.

Comment: as you did  in your sample ...check better  .. insert is not an update  so the rows  are not replaced  but are added

Comment: "Nothing wrong with it." only thing it can cause a large (disk) based temporary table to handle to copy large tables which can be bad.. @Cid

Comment: @RaymondNijland That comment wasn't about perf/resources usage, but about the syntax.

Comment: "That comment wasn't about perf/resources usage, but about the syntax" Well i didn't say the syntax was bad  @Cid

Comment: *"In fact t2 is created by duplicating t1"* and then *"Result - t1.rows are just replaced by t2.rows !!"*. Isn't it rather that the query failed (no changes since they contain the sames values ?)

Comment: @RaymondNijland then, I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Cid, total count of rows in `t1` must be duplicated after inserting, but that's not happend.

Comment: If I was testing this I would get the counts from both tables before the insert and then a count of table 1 after the insert and if the after insert count for table1 = count of table1 + count of table 2 before insert then good. If not I would start to look for what was lost. An insert will not replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

You can find more example [here in w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

I didn't get the point of merging to identical tables though..

Comment: i guess you never found https://www.w3fools.com/ ? "When W3Fools was launched in 2011, the state of documentation for developers was poor. This site documented many content errors and issues with the W3Schools website Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns"  Notice it says "largely resolved' better is to link to the real MySQL documentation instead not w3school

Comment: I think it is easier to understand examples from w3school, but I get your point. Here's the link to the MySql oficial documentation [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: I found stupid things in W3School. Last I noticed was concerning `MAX()` parameter. W3School : *"Required. A numeric value (can be a field or a formula)"* (nothing else). MySQL Official doc : *"may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the maximum string value"*